# Xpath extract text after using attribute selectors

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, html-parsing

I want to extract some text from a HTML file with just Xpath code. I get the the text extracted in Chrome console  with:

1) `TEXT=$x('//*[@id="olpOfferListColumn"]')`

2) `TEXT[0].innerText`

But  now, I want combine these two commands in one with just XPath. 
I tried of course staff like :

```
TEXT=$x('//*[@id="olpOfferListColumn"]/text()')
```

or

```
TEXT=$x('//*[@id="olpOfferListColumn"]/::text()')
```

Comment: And where is HTML?

Comment: The html ist very long. That is why did not  pasted it . That is this web page  :  https://www.amazon.de/gp/offer-listing/B001U309KW/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new         If you put the two commands in the the  browser console , you will understand what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `//*[@id="olpOfferListColumn"]/text()` means to return you *child text nodes*. But `#olpOfferListColumn` element has no *child text nodes*, but *descendant text nodes* (to get *all descendant text nodes* you might need to use `//*[@id="olpOfferListColumn"]//text()`)
2. `//*[@id="olpOfferListColumn"]/::text()` - invalid XPath

Try

```
string(//*[@id="olpOfferListColumn"])
```

to get all text content (analogue of innerText property) of `#olpOfferListColumn`

Comment: Great to know string()

Answer (score 0):

To extract text of specific `id` element,

```
xpath = '//*[@id="olpOfferListColumn"]/text()'
```

it will get the text of element with `id=olpOfferListCloumn`

if you want every text node in specific element

use:

```
xpath = '//*[@id="olpOfferListColumn"]//text()'
```

Comment: does not work ....  already tried .....  that is why I  posted the question please check the text of my question

Comment: Then data might be in `inner elements`.
For that to extract, you use `//` while extracting data. check updated answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It does not work  in my case, I got some text elements but not text contents.  And that is what is important.